# modprobe blacklist not working Debian 11

Tags: kernel, modprobe

I dont like the intel mei kernel modules so I made a file in `/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf` that has the following contents:

```
blacklist mei
blacklist mei_mei
blacklist mei_hdcp
blacklist mei_wdt
```

It works for everything except `mei` and `mei_me` as shown by the output of `lsmod | grep mei`:

```
mei_me                 45056  0
mei                   139264  1 mei_me
```

The only solution I've found is to manually delete the .ko files, but every time the kernel updates then the kernel modules get re added.

On other systems I've used this doesnt happen, there is no need to manually delete the files.

Anyone got any insight into why this might be happening?

Comment: Well, you're not blacklisting `mei_me`.

Comment: Whoops didnt see that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this option : [Blacklist with fake install](https://wiki.debian.org/KernelModuleBlacklisting)

add the following line to your `/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf`

```
install mei /bin/true
```

Then:

```
sudo depmod -ae
sudo update-initramfs -u
```